# My discord bot loops a lot of messages (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord.js, embed

I try to create a bot who replies the picture. Its working, but some second later the bots send the embed again without a picture and loop this (Check picture below)

```js
client.on('message' , (message) => {
    var content = message.content.split(" "); 

    const channel = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "spam")
    const messageinput = `${message.content}`
    let messageAttachment = message.attachments.size > 0 ? message.attachments.array()[0].url : null

    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
        embed.setAuthor("Test")
        if (messageAttachment) embed.setImage(messageAttachment)
        embed.setColor(16689911);
    message.channel.send(embed)  
})
```

This is the output:

[image: This is the output]

Answer (score 0):

The bot is looping over and over again because it's in reaction to it's own message that it send. You can prevent this by making sure that the message author wasn't a bot.

```js
client.on('message' , (message) => {

if (message.author.bot) return 

var content = message.content.split(" "); 

const channel = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "spam")
const messageinput = `${message.content}`
let messageAttachment = message.attachments.size > 0 ? message.attachments.array()[0].url : null

let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
    embed.setAuthor("Test")
    if (messageAttachment) embed.setImage(messageAttachment)
    embed.setColor(16689911);
message.channel.send(embed)
 
})
```